# unity can't destroy child object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to delete a specific child object, but it just won't get destroyed. I even tried 4 different ways to destroy it but none of them worked. Strangely, I dont get any errors in the console.

```
DestroyImmediate(prefabParent.GetComponent<Transform>().GetChild(Select.instance.ID).gameObject);

Destroy(prefabParent.GetComponent<Transform>().GetChild(Select.instance.ID).gameObject);

DestroyImmediate(prefabParent.transform.GetChild(Select.instance.ID).gameObject);

Destroy(prefabParent.transform.GetChild(Select.instance.ID).gameObject);
```

this is how Select looks like

```
public static Select instance;

public int ID;

private void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}

public void SetTarget(int _ID)
{
    ID = _ID;
}
```

extra information:

this script is meant to delete a button prefab from a dynamic scrollview

Comment: what is `Select`?

Comment: @MiladQasemi, a public class, I just renamed it because it would've been too long otherwise

Comment: why are you getting instance id?

Comment: select contains a public int called ID.

Comment: does GetChild returns the correct gameobject trasnform?

Comment: @MiladQasemi, Yes, it does.

Comment: where do you call the Destroy method?

Comment: @MiladQasemi, from a button

Comment: if you put a debug.log instead of destroy it gets called?

Comment: @MiladQasemi, Yes, it does. this is what shows up in the console: Option(Clone) (UnityEngine.GameObject)

Comment: What is "prefabParent"? Are you accidentally trying to delete the child in the prefab, rather than the child in the scene?

Comment: @ipodtouch0218, prefabParent is the content of a scrollview and as the name implies, it is the parent of all the prefabs

Comment: You are accessing the `Select` instance using a static class variable.   That static variable is set in Awake for each instance of `Select`, but only one of them can occupy that variable (the last one to execute the `instance = this;` line).

Comment: @hijinxbassist, It works perfectly fine with Debug.Log, so why is it a problem?

Comment: I believe the issue is caused by the static variable.  Please post a minimum reproducible example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't pretty efficient but can't we use loops and check each?

```
foreach (Transform child in transform)
{
    if (child.gameObject.GetInstanceID() == ID)
    {
        Destroy(child.gameObject);
        break;
    }
}
```